# Should I use "get" or "got" here?

Tags: tense, difference, british-english, spoken-english

> They finally get their way.

Or

> They finally got their way.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both, but it depends *when* the time setting is

> They finally **get** their way.

would be said just after they get approval

> They finally **got** their way.

is for any time in the past.

> It was two years of struggle *until* they finally **get** their way.
>   It was two years of struggle *then* they finally **got** their way.

Then there is

> They *always* get their way.
>   *they have in the past and* ***will always*** *in the future have their way*
>
> They *always* got their way.
>   *they have in the past and* ***will probably*** *in the future have their way*

Comment: So if they get their approval today or some hours ago then "get" but if the approval has happened yesterday or any time in the past then "got" ?

Comment: They finally get their way would be historical present and very advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct depending on context and tense.

“Got their way” would be correct in both cases, “get their way” would only work in present tense.